# Swift: TableViewCell hightlights the whole cell when selected instead only the image view

Tags: ios, swift, tableview

so here is how my setup looks like: [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y3NoE.png)

As you can see I use TableViewsCells then I place ImageViews inside the cell. But as you can see on the screenshot whenever I hold my finger over the tableview it hightlights the whole cell area not the ImageView that acts as background ,so how can I make sure that it highlights the background Image only? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the `selectionStyle` to `.none` in your `UITableViewCell` then override `isSelected`.

```
override var isSelected: Bool {
    didSet {
        // do whatever you want to your image here
    }
}
```